# Having troubles with deployment of custom filtered lookup field.

Tags: migration-tool

Whey trying to deploy code with ant migration tool, got the following error on filtered lookup field on custom object

```
duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>
```

Comment: Are you trying to deploy only one field? <>Object name. Field name<> ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to overwrite your custom object. Try to deploy only field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account.Industry</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Uploading a single field is not applicable. I am trying to make legacy code 'deployable' via Continuous Integration. It would be great to understand a reason of this issue